# merging columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Want to merge column elements to a single column

```
X <- tribble(
~X1,  ~X2, ~X3,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
7, 8, 9)

apply(X, 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse=""))
```

What would be dplyr version of this code?

Comment: For your base R, there is also the vectorized `do.call(paste0, X)`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

X %>% 
  mutate(foo = pmap_chr(., paste0)) %>% 
  pull()
# [1] "123" "456" "789"
```

Or directly:

```
pmap_chr(X, paste0)
```

(though there is no more `dplyr` here :)

---

And a simpler base R version could be:

```
do.call(paste0, X)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr-purrr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
X %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
purrr::map_dfr(.,paste0,collapse="")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 147   258   369
```

Or:

```
 X %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
 purrr::map_chr(.,paste0,collapse="")
   X1    X2    X3 
"147" "258" "369"
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::unite()` would be a natural fit if you want to modify the input data frame:

```r
X <- tibble::tribble(
  ~X1, ~X2, ~X3,
  1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9
)

tidyr::unite(X, new, X1:X3, sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   new  
#>   <chr>
#> 1 123  
#> 2 456  
#> 3 789
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>